# Boxed Equations aligned at "="

Tags: equations, align, box

trying to achieve a structured, boxed equation, which is aligned at the "=". I googled for quite a time, maybe I used the wrong keywords bur I only found equations that are centred, or only one lined, but never aligned to "=". May best solution until now is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\setlength\fboxsep{0.5cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
  log_{b} a \overset{!}{=} \frac{lg(a)}{lg(b)} \\
  \\
  10^x=2 \\
  x=lg(2) \\
  10^{lg(2)}=2 \\
  \\
  a^n=c \\
  10^{lg(a)}^{n}=10^{lg(c)} \\
  10^{lg(a) /cdot n}=10^{lg(c)} \\
  lg(a)/cdot n=lg(c) \\
\end{empheq}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Sadly it doesn't display the \cdot 
AND it gives me a double superscript error because of the "^" 
AND I don't know how to define that it should align all lines to the "=", like in Microsoft Word f.e.

:/

Please, if someone would be so kind to deliver a short solution for this? :)
Thx

Comment: You have put `/cdot` instead of `\cdot`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: My humble suggestion. Or you use amsmath, or mathtools. No togheter.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `empheq` for this. In any case, there is no need for `center` around `empheq`; it's actually wrong to add it.

If you want to align the equals sign, tell TeX to with `&`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\fboxsep{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\[
\boxed{\begin{aligned}
  \log_{b} a &\overset{!}{=} \frac{\lg(a)}{\lg(b)} \\
  \\
  10^x&=2 \\
  x&=\lg(2) \\
  10^{\lg(2)}&=2 \\
  \\
  a^n&=c \\
  10^{\lg(a^{n})}&=10^{\lg(c)} \\
  10^{\lg(a) \cdot n}&=10^{\lg(c)} \\
  \lg(a)\cdot n&=\lg(c)
\end{aligned}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\log` and `\lg`; also `\cdot` and not `/cdot`. I fixed the mathematical error in line 6.

Using “lg” for the base 10 logarithm is not common. In computer science it usually denotes the base 2 logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

- You should write `\lg` instead of `lg`
- For a double superscript, we should write `{a^b}^c`
- For the alignment, you have to put `&` before the `=`

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\setlength\fboxsep{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
  \log_{b} a & \overset{!}{=} \frac{\lg(a)}{\lg(b)} \\[1em]
  10^x& =2 \\
  x& =\lg(2) \\
  10^{\lg(2)}& =2 \\[1em]
  a^n& =c \\
  {10^{\lg(a)}}^{n} & =10^{\lg(c)} \\
  10^{\lg(a) \cdot n} & =10^{\lg(c)} \\
  \lg(a)\cdot n & =\lg(c) 
\end{empheq}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of the above code]

Comment: Wow thank you kindly. Very good. I am new to all this and at the start sometimes it is a bit overwhelming all at once....

Answer (score 2):

I guess *lg* denotes  the `\log` function, and *cdot*, `\cdots`. The aligned environments (there are several)  do not guess where you want to align, and  you have to mark the alignment point with an ampersand. If you don't, they're by default aligned at the end of lines.

Unrelated remarks: you don't have to use the `center` environment for these equations, as they *are* centred. It only adds spurious vertical spacing  to the normal spacing of equations. Also, if you load `empheq`, needless to load `amsmath` nor `mathtools`, as the former package already does it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{empheq}
\setlength\fboxsep{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
  \log_{b} a & \overset{!}{=} \frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)} \\
  \\
  10^x & =2 \\
  x & =\log(2) \\
  10^{\log(2)} & =2 \\
  \\
  a^n & =c \\
 { 10^{\log(a)}}^{n} & =10^{\log(c)} \\
  10^{\log(a) /\cdot n} & =10^{\log(c)} \\
  \log(a)/\cdot n & =\log(c)
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly! Also appreciate the "Unrelated remarks". didn't know that, really usefull!